# How to get paypal partner name and vandor name for credit card from paypal pro setup in magneto 2

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, paypal-payments-pro, paypal-pro

**I am trying set up paypal pro in magneto 2** with sand box credentials.Here for paypal pro it need partner ,user,vendor,password.**Can any please tell me that from paypal account**, from where can i get mainly **vendor** and **partner** then user and password details.